# Market analysis project - cryptocurrencies

Tags: r, analysis, cryptocurrency

```
+#I just started to code for some cryptocurrencies analysis. But I just encounterd an issue with the code.
    _____________________________________________________________________________

        library(magrittr)
        library(dplyr)
        library(tidyverse)
        library(crypto)
        library(lubridate)
        library(xts)
        library(quantmod)
        library(tidyr)

        df <- getCoins(limit = 50)

        yourfunction <- function(df, frequency = NULL) {
          freq        <- frequency
          df$date     <- lubridate::round_date(df$date, freq)
          data        <-
            df %>% dplyr::group_by(date, slug, symbol, name, ranknow) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(
              open   = dplyr::first(open),
              high   = max(high),
              low    = min(low),
              close  = dplyr::last(close),
              volume = sum(volume),
              market = dplyr::last(market))
          data$volume <- round(data$volume, digits = 0)
          data$market <- round(data$market, digits = 0)
          data        <- as.data.frame(data)
          results <- xts::xts(data[, 2:ncol(data)], as.POSIXct(data[, 1], format =
                                                                 "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
          return(results)
        }

        #### IF NO ERRORS IN ABOVE RUN THESE INDIVIDUALLY------
week_xts  <- yourfunction(df, frequency = "week")
str(week_xts)

as.tbl(week_xts) %>%
  select(date, slug, open) %>%
  spread(slug, open) %>%
  tail()

#### IF NO ERRORS IN ABOVE RUN THESE INDIVIDUALLY------
month_xts <- yourfunction(df, frequency = "month")
str(month_xts)

as.tbl(month_xts) %>%
  select(date, slug, open) %>%
  spread(slug, open) %>%
  tail()
########################



#Making daily, weekly and monthly open for ten biggest coins

daily_open <- spread(df[,c(1,4,6)],slug,open)
weekly_open <- spread(week_xts[,c(1, 2, 6)],slug,open)
monthly_open <- spread(month_xts[,c(1, 2, 6)],slug,open)

ten_biggest <- c(list_of_coins[1:10,"slug"])

daily_open <- daily_open[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_open <- weekly_open[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_open <- monthly_open[,c("date",ten_biggest)]


#Making daily, weekly and monthly high for ten biggest coins

daily_high <- spread(df[,c(1,4,7)],slug,high)
weekly_high <- spread(week_xts[,c(1,2,7)],slug,high)
monthly_high <- spread(month_xts[,c(1,2,7)],slug,high)

daily_high <- daily_high[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_high <- weekly_high[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_high <- monthly_high[,c("date",ten_biggest)]

#Making daily, weekly and monthly low for ten biggest coins

daily_low <- spread(df[,c(1,4,8)],slug,low)
weekly_low <- spread(week_xts[,c(1,2,8)],slug,low)
monthly_low <- spread(month_xts[,c(1,2,8)],slug,low)

daily_low <- daily_low[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_low <- weekly_low[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_low <- monthly_low[,c("date",ten_biggest)]

#Making daily, weekly and monthly close for ten biggest coins

daily_close <- spread(df[,c(1,4,9)],slug,close)
weekly_close <- spread(week_xts[,c(1,2,9)],slug,close)
monthly_close <- spread(month_xts[,c(1,2,9)],slug,close) 

daily_close <- daily_close[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_close <- weekly_close[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_close <- monthly_close[,c("date",ten_biggest)]


#Making daily, weekly and monthly volume for ten biggest coins

daily_volume <- spread(df[,c(1,4,10)],slug,volume)
weekly_volume <- spread(week_xts[,c(1,2,10)],slug,volume)
monthly_volume <- spread(month_xts[,c(1,2,10)],slug,volume)

daily_volume <- daily_volume[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_volume <- weekly_volume[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_volume <- monthly_volume[,c("date",ten_biggest)]


#Making daily,weekly and monthly market for ten biggest coins

daily_market <- spread(df[,c(1,4,11)],slug,market)
weekly_market <- spread(week_xts[,c(1,2,11)],slug,market)
monthly_market <- spread(month_xts[,c(1,2,11)],slug,market)

daily_market <- daily_market[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
weekly_market <- weekly_market[,c("date",ten_biggest)]
monthly_market <- monthly_market[,c("date",ten_biggest)]


#Doesn't work
weekly_open_returns <- periodReturn(weekly_open, period="daily", subset=NULL, type="arithmetic",leading="TRUE")
weekly_open_returns <- Return.calculate(weekly_open)
```

I would like to make a data frame for each data type (open, high, close, volume, market, close_ratio and spread) for daily, monthly and weekly frequencies. These data frames should be constructed in a way that each column represents one currency and the rows would represent observations. However, when I try to use spread function for weekly and  monthly frequencies in order to do this, it gives an error. How should I proceed?

Thank you in advance for help. Have a pleasant day.

The errors are:

```
    > weekly_open_returns <- periodReturn(weekly_open, period="daily", subset=NULL, type="arithmetic",leading="TRUE")
Error in try.xts(x) : 
  Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> weekly_open_returns <- Return.calculate(weekly_open)
Error in checkData(prices, method = "xts") : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

(From comment:)

I would like to make a data frame for each data type (open, high, close, volume, market, close_ratio and spread) for daily, monthly and weekly frequencies. These data frames should be constructed in a way that each column represents one currency and the rows would represent observations. However, when I try to use spread function for weekly and monthly frequencies in order to do this, it gives an error. How should I proceed? Thank you in advance for help. Have a pleasant day. – MP PM 28 mins ago

Comment: I would like to make a data frame for each data type (open, high, close, volume, market, close_ratio and spread) for daily, monthly and weekly frequencies. These data frames should be constructed in a way that each column represents one currency and the rows would represent observations. 
However, when I try to use spread function for weekly and  monthly frequencies in order to do this, it gives an error.
How should I proceed? Thank you in advance for help. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: I suggested an edit to better format the error code. I also added the comment to your question: please know that some comments may be hidden (when there are a lot of them), and even if not some readers when looking for help will not read the comments, so when it is that relevant to the question (your comment here is *key*), you should edit the question and add (perhaps with an "**Update**" note) and/or fix things.

Comment: Thank you for the help with formating and suggestions for the future.

Comment: I'm deleting my previous comment, since it does not accurately give you credit for what you provided, my apologies. Might I suggest, though, that you try to reduce your problem somewhat? Your question is not with the acquisition of the data, so I suggest you can remove all libraries and code that retrieves it, and instead paste the output from `dput(head(df,n=10))`. There are a *lot* of packages being loaded here, and my guess is that almost all of them are ancillary to the relevant code; large code chunks scare away some answerers.

Comment: For clarity: no need for `install.packages(...)`, just `library(...)` for all *relevant* packages. I removed `PerformanceAnalytics` since it looks like the code here does not use it. Also, `tidyverse` includes `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `lubridate` among others, so you can simplify your own code if you'd like (it's just nearly redundant, no harm done). I don't think you're using `quantmod`, so that can probably be removed as well. (My theme: give us as much code as we need to reproduce, but no more if possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the code, the error is fairly clear: `tidyr::spread` works on tibbles, but what you have is class `[1] "xts" "zoo"`. Additionally, likely because of the `xts` step, it is all `character`, meaning all of your numbers in `week_xts` are strings. I see what you think you are doing with `daily_xts` (post-`spread`), but most of the data will be `NA` since most of the currencies are not present until late in the data. Is this intentional?

Part of the problem is your use of `xts`: it does not return a `data.frame`, it returns a vector or `matrix`, as shown here:

```
str(week_xts)
# An 'xts' object on 2013-04-27 17:00:00/2018-04-28 17:00:00 containing:
#   Data: chr [1:4593, 1:10] "bitcoin" "litecoin" "bitcoin" "litecoin" "bitcoin" ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:10] "slug" "symbol" "name" "ranknow" ...
#   Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
#   xts Attributes:  
#  NULL
```

This says that everything is `character`. So if you do

```
head(week_xts[,1:5])
#                     slug       symbol name       ranknow open          
# 2013-04-27 17:00:00 "bitcoin"  "BTC"  "Bitcoin"  " 1"    "  135.300000"
# 2013-04-27 17:00:00 "litecoin" "LTC"  "Litecoin" " 7"    "    4.300000"
# 2013-05-04 17:00:00 "bitcoin"  "BTC"  "Bitcoin"  " 1"    "  116.380000"
# 2013-05-04 17:00:00 "litecoin" "LTC"  "Litecoin" " 7"    "    3.780000"
# 2013-05-11 17:00:00 "bitcoin"  "BTC"  "Bitcoin"  " 1"    "  113.200000"
# 2013-05-11 17:00:00 "litecoin" "LTC"  "Litecoin" " 7"    "    3.400000"
```

you'll see that what you want as numbers are actually strings.

I suggest that perhaps `yourfunction` should not be doing an `xts::xts` before you `spread` things. instead:

```
yourfunction <- function(df, frequency = NULL) {
  # ...
  return(data)
}
week_xts  <- yourfunction(df, frequency = "week")
str(week_xts)
# 'data.frame': 4593 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ date   : Date, format: "2013-04-28" "2013-04-28" ...
#  $ slug   : chr  "bitcoin" "litecoin" "bitcoin" "litecoin" ...
#  $ symbol : chr  "BTC" "LTC" "BTC" "LTC" ...
#  $ name   : chr  "Bitcoin" "Litecoin" "Bitcoin" "Litecoin" ...
#  $ ranknow: num  1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 1 7 ...
#  $ open   : num  135.3 4.3 116.38 3.78 113.2 ...
#  $ high   : num  147.49 4.57 125.6 4.04 122 ...
#  $ low    : num  107.72 3.52 79.1 2.4 103.5 ...
#  $ close  : num  116.99 3.8 113.57 3.41 114.22 ...
#  $ volume : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ market : num  1542820000 73901200 1219450000 57196300 1242760000 ...
```

From there:

```
as.tbl(week_xts) %>%
  select(date, slug, open) %>%
  spread(slug, open) %>%
  tail()
# # A tibble: 6 x 51
#   date        `0x`  aelf aeternity `binance-coin` bitcoin `bitcoin-cash`
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 2018-03-25 0.583 0.633      1.75           10.0   8939.          1033.
# 2 2018-04-01 0.635 0.625      1.64           11.7   7979.           862.
# 3 2018-04-08 0.521 0.519      1.43           12.2   6849.           649.
# 4 2018-04-15 0.597 0.895      1.47           12.4   6955.           666.
# 5 2018-04-22 0.923 1.11       1.86           12.3   8159.           891.
# 6 2018-04-29 1.01  1.02       2.3            13.4   8867.          1290.
# # ... with 44 more variables: `bitcoin-diamond` <dbl>, `bitcoin-gold` <dbl>,
# #   `bitcoin-private` <dbl>, bitshares <dbl>, `bytecoin-bcn` <dbl>,
# #   bytom <dbl>, cardano <dbl>, dash <dbl>, decred <dbl>, digixdao <dbl>,
# #   dogecoin <dbl>, eos <dbl>, ethereum <dbl>, `ethereum-classic` <dbl>,
# #   icon <dbl>, iota <dbl>, lisk <dbl>, litecoin <dbl>, loopring <dbl>,
# #   maker <dbl>, mixin <dbl>, monero <dbl>, nano <dbl>, nem <dbl>, neo <dbl>,
# #   omisego <dbl>, ontology <dbl>, populous <dbl>, qtum <dbl>, rchain <dbl>,
# #   ripple <dbl>, siacoin <dbl>, status <dbl>, steem <dbl>, stellar <dbl>,
# #   stratis <dbl>, tether <dbl>, tron <dbl>, vechain <dbl>, verge <dbl>,
# #   wanchain <dbl>, waves <dbl>, zcash <dbl>, zilliqa <dbl>
```

(I show the `tail` of it because the majority of early dates are empty for most currencies.)

Side note: I suggest you use `select(...)` and column names instead of indices; you used `week_xts[,c(1,5)]` which matches `date` and `open`, yes, but it is not abundantly clear without looking at the data. Also, by skipping the `xts` conversion, it's now `c(1,2,6)` to capture date, slug, and open.

I wonder if this is the point you should consider using `xts::xts`, though with `slug` in the data, you'll likely still be converting all numbers to `character`.

---

20 of the last date's entries, if somebody else wants a quick gander at this:

```
> dput(head(filter(df, date==tail(date,1)),n=20))
structure(list(slug = c("bitcoin", "ethereum", "ripple", "bitcoin-cash", 
"eos", "cardano", "litecoin", "stellar", "tron", "neo", "iota", 
"dash", "monero", "nem", "tether", "vechain", "ethereum-classic", 
"qtum", "omisego", "icon"), symbol = c("BTC", "ETH", "XRP", "BCH", 
"EOS", "ADA", "LTC", "XLM", "TRX", "NEO", "MIOTA", "DASH", "XMR", 
"XEM", "USDT", "VEN", "ETC", "QTUM", "OMG", "ICX"), name = c("Bitcoin", 
"Ethereum", "Ripple", "Bitcoin Cash", "EOS", "Cardano", "Litecoin", 
"Stellar", "TRON", "NEO", "IOTA", "Dash", "Monero", "NEM", "Tether", 
"VeChain", "Ethereum Classic", "Qtum", "OmiseGO", "ICON"), date = structure(c(17651, 
17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 
17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 17651, 
17651), class = "Date"), ranknow = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), open = c(9426.11, 
689.76, 0.871404, 1440.96, 21.64, 0.364297, 153.65, 0.458688, 
0.089656, 92.15, 2.04, 498.44, 256.35, 0.42658, 0.997553, 4.83, 
21.84, 23.15, 18.05, 4.69), high = c(9477.14, 694.44, 0.876788, 
1440.96, 21.64, 0.364297, 154.08, 0.460128, 0.101197, 94.76, 
2.05, 499.43, 259.07, 0.42658, 1.01, 4.83, 22.95, 25.6, 18.06, 
4.69), low = c(9166.81, 666.12, 0.831208, 1339.36, 16.86, 0.336625, 
147.87, 0.417446, 0.086102, 82.86, 1.94, 472.02, 239.08, 0.403889, 
0.992921, 4.37, 21.42, 22.12, 16.81, 4.26), close = c(9240.55, 
669.92, 0.837938, 1350.05, 17.58, 0.343318, 148.48, 0.424659, 
0.093777, 84.27, 1.96, 472.77, 242.46, 0.40888, 0.998919, 4.49, 
21.68, 22.64, 16.95, 4.34), volume = c(8673920000, 2853100000, 
575364000, 753114000, 4073370000, 298712000, 341397000, 81453300, 
1749640000, 377385000, 61762500, 118497000, 103574000, 25523800, 
4498440000, 109782000, 351049000, 414455000, 68967800, 94284100
), market = c(160302000000, 68376400000, 34112200000, 24642000000, 
17849100000, 9445160000, 8651810000, 8518430000, 5894710000, 
5990010000, 5676530000, 4006280000, 4096790000, 3839220000, 2411230000, 
2539730000, 2215850000, 2050300000, 1841910000, 1815430000), 
    close_ratio = c(0.2376, 0.1342, 0.1477, 0.1052, 0.1506, 0.2419, 
    0.0982, 0.169, 0.5084, 0.1185, 0.1818, 0.0274, 0.1691, 0.22, 
    0.3512, 0.2609, 0.1699, 0.1494, 0.112, 0.186), spread = c(310.33, 
    28.32, 0.05, 101.6, 4.78, 0.03, 6.21, 0.04, 0.02, 11.9, 0.11, 
    27.41, 19.99, 0.02, 0.02, 0.46, 1.53, 3.48, 1.25, 0.43)), .Names = c("slug", 
"symbol", "name", "date", "ranknow", "open", "high", "low", "close", 
"volume", "market", "close_ratio", "spread"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```